# strange signs in Documentviewer WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, xps, documentviewer

I'm adding a document viewer to my WPF project and all seems perfect. But when I try to open another xps file, the documentviewer places some [?] signs in my document.

Here's my code :

```
 if (xps != null)
                {
                    xps.Close();
                    xps = null;
                }

                docViewer.Document = null;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application eApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook eWb;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet eWs;

                eApp.Visible = false;

                eWb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(gekozenProductBestand, false,false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                eWs = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)eWb.Worksheets[1];
                eWs.PageSetup.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
                eWb.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypeXPS, System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "producten", XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, true, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing);

                eApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                eApp.Quit();
                xps = new XpsDocument(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "producten.xps", System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

                docViewer.Document = xps.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
                docViewer.FitToWidth();


                eApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                eWs = null;
                eWb = null;
                eApp.Quit();
                eApp = null;

                GC.Collect();
```

And finally an image to make myself clear :
http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/7043/knipselq.png

Comment: It looks like a character encoding issue. I think XPS is Unicode by default so that's what you should be feeding it. Also, look into using named parameters to simplify the calling code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178843.aspx

Comment: The first time that I load my document everything runs normal, but when I load a file the second time it gives me those [?] , so normally it's not the unicode .

Comment: I found the solution : 

when I try to re-use the created xps file, I get the [?] symbols.
Probably the file isn't released internally, so you have to create a new file for each document you want to show. (And delete the old one afterwards of course).

Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. think about not using GC.Collect though http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/clr/thread/2f40d16c-cd1d-44db-ab55-256ab7b0ef68